# false condition evaluating true in while loop

Tags: c++, debugging

I've been debugging this simple piece of code , and I'm still not getting why while loop is being entered on condition evaluating to false. Here's the code :

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned long count = 1; // we assume 2 has been found.
unsigned long primeArr[3] = {0};

bool primeArrCanDiv(unsigned long n){
    for(unsigned long i = 0; i<count; i++){
        if(n%primeArr[i] == 0) return true;
    }
    primeArr[count] = n;
    return false;
}


int main(){
    unsigned long j=3;
    primeArr[0]=2;
    while(count<3){
        if(!primeArrCanDiv(j)) count++;
        ++j;
    }
    std::cout<<primeArr[count-1];
    return 0;
}
```

a bit about the code , introduces 2 global var `count = 1` and an array `primeArr[3]`. Now the following part should run till count reaches 3 :

```
while(count<3){
        if(!primeArrCanDiv(j)) count++;
        ++j;
    }
```

But it runs 2 times more than it should , even when count gets = 3 , which should make `3<3` evaluate to false , right? But it stops when count reaches to 4.

adding `std::cout<<primeArr[count-1];` will print 7 instead of 5.

I've tried debugging it inside nemiver , which shows condition being evaluated to `false` and still it enters the loop. I know I might have left something silly of my mind ,still would like to know what's causing this.

Screenshot :

[image]

Using exact : `g++ -g q7.cpp -o a.out` with gcc -v `gcc version 5.1.0 (GCC)` on x64 arch linux

Comment: @Prabhu , I've tried debugging with nemiver , it shows condition being evaluated to `false` as well as count = 3. and that too 2 times :/

Comment: "why while loop is being entered on condition evaluating to false" – **it doesn't.** If the loop body is executed, then the condition **was** true.

Comment: [Can not reproduce](http://ideone.com/j0AAu3)

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant screenshot added.

Comment: Suggestion - don't inline statements and conditionals together. Always but the action on a seperate line from the "if" clause. For example: `if(!primeArrCanDiv(j)) count++;`  - move the `count++;` statement to the next line and indented. Bonus points if you add curly braces. This makes the code both easier to read and to debug.  Keeping the conditional expression and the subsequent statement on the same line might cause odd behavior in the debugger that makes you think it's doing something that it's really not.

Comment: @selbie ookay , got it. And now it's correct. Can you post an answer so I can mark it :) Btw I still do not get why does this happen on my toolset , while not on others. complier inconsistency?

Comment: for(unsigned long i = 0; i<count; i++){if(n%primeArr[i] == 0) return true;} can be much simpler. if(count < 2) return true; gives you the same results.

Comment: @kyho3 that's not the count you're thinking. count is total num of Prime numbers discovered yet.

Comment: So just to be clear - you're just talking about the debugger making it look like the loop has been entered?  Does the `primeArrCanDiv(j)` function call actually get made or `j` actually get incremented?  I suspect not. As an FYI, this seems to be a common quirk with debuggers - they might make it appear that a loop is being entered, and with one or two more 'steps' will then jump out of the loop.  I'm not sure of the exact reason(s) for this behavior, but it's behavior I have gotten used to over the years.

Comment: @MichaelBurr yes loop was entered and function was called as well as entered. 2 times. That's why it printed 7 instead of 5.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal: simply moving the `count++` expression to the next line (as suggested by @selbie) fixed the problem? If so, I'd like to ask you to try moving it back to the same line as the `if`.  After you do that, if the problem comes back then you have uncovered a compiler bug. If the problem doesn't come back then your previous debug session was probably running with a stale binary that out of sync with the source code for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP asked me to make my comment into an answer.  Here goes.

You should avoid inlining statements and conditionals together. Always put the action on a seperate line from the "if" clause. For example:

```
if(!primeArrCanDiv(j)) count++;
```

Move the count++; statement to the next line and indented. Bonus points if you add curly braces.

This is much better C/C++ style:

```
if(!primeArrCanDiv(j))
{
    count++;
}
```

This makes the code both easier to read and to debug. Keeping the conditional expression and the subsequent statement on the same line might confuse some visual debuggers to show odd results. It definitely makes it easier for the person stepping through the code with the debugger to see which statements are actually executed.

Comment: While this may be good general advice, I'm curious how this solved the problem of the loop being entered too many times.  The OP specifically said in the comments that it wasn't a case of the debugger acting in a confusing manner - the `primeArrCanDiv(j)` was actually being called too many times.  I'm hoping that @AbhinavGauniyal  can explain.

Comment: @MichaelBurr to be honest , I've no idea how it worked. I'm 100% sure that I wasn't using a stale binary , I manually built the code each time I was debugging , I tried to reproduce this problem again and again with nemiver and was successful each time. Also I am aware of this answer cannot logically solve my problem and I'm just counting on some bug with nemiver or gcc. Since I saw this comment I tried to replicate this code again and test it on nemiver but was unsuccessful this time , but then again I'm using Arch linux and gcc might have been updated since. I just hope it was solved.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal: Oh well, sometimes things happen that just can't be explained.  Must have driven you crazy.

Comment: Also to be clear , the screenshot I've posted might confuse someone that count is being incremented on that line , but that line hasn't updated the values as well as it showed same results on the line above too. I was baffled by this scenario too and I'm happy that I do have a screenshot to prove this , otherwise I might not have belived myself in future lol.

Answer (score 1):

I just compiled and executed your code in Visual Studio 2013

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned long count = 1; // we assume 2 has been found.
unsigned long primeArr[3] = { 0 };

bool primeArrCanDiv(unsigned long n){
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i<count; i++){
        if (n%primeArr[i] == 0) return true;
    }
    primeArr[count] = n;
    return false;
}


int main(){
    unsigned long j = 3;
    primeArr[0] = 2;
    while (count<3){
        if (!primeArrCanDiv(j)) count++;
        ++j;
        std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
foo
foo
foo
```

Your code seems to work as expected. Maybe your toolset is the problem?